# PHP echoing into JavaScript value "0" even when value is not "0" after POSTing with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have button that is using AJAX post method to post value into PHP.

When I echo that value back in JavaScript it's always echoing 0, even when I am 100% sure that value in PHP is not 0.

Here is JavaScript:

```
function slanje(br){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      'broj' : br,
    }
  });   
}

function otvaranje(id, broj){
  slanje(broj);
  var testNumber = <?php echo $br; ?> + "";
```

And PHP (I do file write to check if PHP received correct value):

```
if(isset($_POST['broj'])){
    $br = $_POST['broj'];
    $file = fopen($br . "broj.txt", "w");
    fclose($file);
}
```

Here is what value I get back in Javascript:

[image]

And here is value in PHP:

[image]

Edit 2: I want to post variable in PHP, than get value of element of PHP array with index I passed with ajax. And that without reloading page. I didn't include array part because while I was testing around I couldn't even make it echo back variable I'm passing using AJAX.

Comment: If you post using AJAX the page doesn't get reloaded and consequently the value of testNumber won't be changed.

Comment: That makes sense. Any idea how I should fix that? I mainly change my JavaScript location.href method of work because it needs page to reload and I read here that POST method using AJAX doesn't need page reload. I even tried writing number in file and than reading and echoing it in JavaScript, but no luck.
Edit: But how it's creating file if I didn't refresh page?

Comment: I don't know what you do with testNumber, but either directly assign broj or move it outside the function and reset it in the success handler of $.ajax

Comment: @Quagaar I need to echo PHP array with index I passed with AJAX. But there is no need to complicate this thread more when I see where problem is.

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to go with the page reload and just submit the values using a form.

Comment: @Quagaar Page is dynamically edited from values that users input, any refresh would ruin it...

Comment: If you are not reloading page, you have to return this value from server via ajax and use it after. Also it is hard to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Ajax with POST means that the client types something (like in a chat), then with AJAX you send that text to the server.  It doesn't make sense to echo a variable with php, then send that value back to the server.  What you are doing is not AJAX.  Could you edit your post and explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using AJAX, then let your PHP script return the POSTed value and grab it in the success handler of the AJAX request.
For the success handler to be able to change the value of `testNumber`, the variable has to be declared outside of `function otvaranje`.

Here are the necessary modifications (also take note of the comments I added):

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['broj'])){
    $br = $_POST['broj'];
    $file = fopen($br . "broj.txt", "w");
    fclose($file);

    // Just output the value and exit
    // If there is business logic doing something with
    // $br, then move this after that code.
    // But remember to only do this if the script was 
    // called with POST, otherwise the initial request 
    // wouldn't work anymore.
    print $br;
    exit;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var testNumber = "<?php echo $br; ?>";

function slanje(br){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'broj' : br,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // called when the request succeeded
            testNumber = data;
        }
    });   
}

function otvaranje(id, broj){
    slanje(broj);
    // move outside: var testNumber = <?php echo $br; ?> + "";
    // rest of function content
}
```

Comment: I didn't try this yet but I have 2 questions. I don't need "var testNumber = <?php echo $br; ?> + "";" , I need just to declare variable testNumber outside of the function to make it global, right? And one more question, can I do "print $array[$br]; exit;" so that it will return value of element of my array with index $br?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to initialize the variable with the PHP echo value. A `var testNumber = '';` would suffice. In the PHP script you can print the value that you need. $br was only my guess. Just remember to check the value of $br before using it as an index into the array.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Very nice way of doing it, I obviously didn't think about it like you because I lack a little bit of AJAX knowledge! Very nice, thanks one more time!